# Program type already present: com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Event

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication, build.gradle

When compiling my project I get the following error message:

> Program type already present:
>   com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Event

**gradle (app)**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.whiteelephant:monthandyearpicker:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.tarun0.zxing-standalone:zxing-standalone:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.edwardvanraak:MaterialBarcodeScanner:0.0.6-ALPHA'
    implementation "ru.tinkoff.scrollingpagerindicator:scrollingpagerindicator:1.0.6"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using this line to add all bundles of google play-service sdk. Instead use only that which you really need.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

Refer [this URL](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) to get the all available play-service SDKs